# code igniter 4 SQL id row automatically adding "/" character after post

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

i want to ask something, i passed a value from controller to view and in database, i wonder how do i delete the "/" character. here's the code

Dashboard.php

```
<form action="/dashboard/post" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value=<?=$userid?>/>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="user_email" id="" class="form-control">
</div>
</form>
```

Controller.php

```
public function index()
    {       
        $model = new DataModel();     
        $user = $model->findAll();
        $hidden_data = [
            'userid' => count($user)
        ];
        return view('dashboard', $hidden_data);
    }
```

[here's the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Azt.png)

honestly i just want to the user_id insert the number only without "/". i knew that sql has auto increment feature but actually i want to create a custom id.

example:
before =
user_id = 10/

after =
user_id = 10

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input field for `user_id` includes the slash, so I assume you get the slash in your PHP code as well.

I recommend you to go step-by-step when issues like this occurs. You know the value that is causing issues, so follow it down to where you notice the error and you can usually find the cause. Often you will notice that it's the most simplest of things that are the cause of the issue, but they are also easily overlooked.

Also, since you include the `user_id` in the form itself you should beware that the user that looks at the page can edit it before submit, so you shouldn't trust that the hidden input is what you set it to be unless you have some sort of validation of it.